# Unable to set focus to text box after custom popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

i'm showing a fancy box message and after message i'm trying to set focus to a textbox.But its not working

here is the html code

```
    <a class="fancyTrigger" href="#TheFancybox"></a>
<hr>
<div id="TheFancybox"></div>

Powered by <a href="http://fancybox.net/" target="_blank">Fancybox</a>

    <input id="ipt" type="textbox" />
```

Javascript code

```
    $("#TheFancybox").html("<p>Just adding a paragraph to demonstrate that you can dynamically create HTML content within a DIV using .html()</p>");

$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox();
$(".fancyTrigger").trigger('click');

$('#ipt').focus();
```

And here is the demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJQj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly for fancybox 2.0.

```
$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox({
    afterShow : function() {
        $('#ipt').focus()
    },
    afterClose : function() {
        $('#ipt').focus()
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i'm doing validation on a form and showing message using fancybox.So each time the element id to focus changes."ipt" in the code will be "ipt2" next time or "ipt3"

Comment: Before closing of popup you can set the id of the element which you want to focus

Comment: I tried like this it's working `beforeClose : function() {
        id = '#ipt1'; // just setting
    },
    afterClose : function() {
        $(id).focus()
    }`

Comment: @iBlue : what Anil proposed works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/YNvdy/ (simplified version) .... having dynamic controls wasn't part of your question.